# Making a Custom Menu Sidebar Icon show as Current in css

Tags: menus, css

In the custom WP Menu I have assigned classes which are different for each menu item. For example

```
.power-icon a {
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    background-image: url(/images/icon-grey.png);
    background-position:  5% 50% ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.power-icon a:hover {
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    background-image: url(/images/icon-blue.png);
    background-position:  5% 50% ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

This works fine, however, I would like to make the blue icon also display when the page is active/current.

I discovered that this

```
      .widget_nav_menu .menu .current-menu-item {
             background-color: #f3f3f3;

      }
```

will highlight the current item background. But my attempts to unify it with the icon class have failed. Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: CSS questions are off topic here and should be better asked on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Sorry Pieter, first timer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really WordPress specific, but here goes.

Really, all you're missing is applying the blue background image on `.current-menu-item a`.

```
/* Default state base */
.widget_nav_menu .menu li a{
  padding-left: 35px !important;
  background-position: 5% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Active state base */
.widget_nav_menu .menu .current-menu-item a,
.widget_nav_menu .menu .current-menu-item a,
.widget_nav_menu .menu .current-menu-parent a,
.widget_nav_menu .menu .current-menu-ancestor a {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

/* Power */
.power-icon a {
  background-image: url( /images/icon-grey.png );
}

/* Power active + hover */
.power-icon a:hover,
.power-icon.current-menu-item a,
.power-icon.current-menu-parent a,
.power-icon.current-menu-ancestor a {
  background-image: url( /images/icon-blue.png );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joey for your time. That works perfect, and I can now see the logic of it. Cheers. Steve